# Show div based on selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown as:

```
<select>
<option value="" selected="selected">Default</option>
<option value="a">first</option>
<option value="b">second</option>
<option value="c">third</option>
<option value="d">fourth</option>
</select>
```

Now accordingly, I have 1 parent div element and 4 children div element

```
<div id="default">
  <div id="a">Random1</div>
  <div id="b">Random2</div>
  <div id="c">Random3</div>
  <div id="d">Random4</div>
</div>
```

So basically, By default the selected option should be default with showing all the div. When the option selected from the dropdown it should show div based on the dropdown value. (Example: if I select **first** then **Random1** should only show and rest gets hidden. similarly, when I select **third** it should only show **Random3** and nothing else).

I hope I am clear.
It would be a great help. Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything yet? what problems have you encountered?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without any external libraries.

It works by attaching an event listener for the `change` event on the `<select>` element and then hiding all the `<div>`s and showing only the selected one.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    for (let otherDiv of document.querySelectorAll('#default div')) {
        otherDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    const div = document.getElementById(this.value);
    div.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```html
<div id="default">
  <div id="a">Random1</div>
  <div id="b">Random2</div>
  <div id="c">Random3</div>
  <div id="d">Random4</div>
</div>

<select id="select">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="a">first</option>
  <option value="b">second</option>
  <option value="c">third</option>
  <option value="d">fourth</option>
</select>
```

---

If you prefer using jQuery, here is an example:

```js
$('#select').change(function () {
    $('#default div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="default">
  <div id="a">Random1</div>
  <div id="b">Random2</div>
  <div id="c">Random3</div>
  <div id="d">Random4</div>
</div>

<select id="select">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="a">first</option>
  <option value="b">second</option>
  <option value="c">third</option>
  <option value="d">fourth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @MatSz Do I have to use CSS in this as I am unable to show the data according to dropdown value only.

Comment: You can use CSS or hide all elements if you want them all hidden initially (your post implied otherwise though).

Comment: Thanks @MatSz. I am able to get the value but it is not showing me the particular div and everything is hidden. I am accepting your answer if possible help me out with the query. Thank you

Comment: You need to make sure the option's value is equal to the target div's id.

Comment: @MatSz  "selected --> r.fn.init [div#a]". This is the value I am getting and I am assuming it's correct only.

Comment: Well, the way this works is by using the option value to find a div of an id of that value. Could you please show your complete code somewhere?

Comment: My bad it is working fine but I have children div the reason it is unable to fetch the data.
 (Eg: 
<div id="a">
  <div>RandomHi</div> 
 <div>RandomHi2</div>                  
 </div>)

I tried using children(), but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Listening to `change` event, change the display property of the divs:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('#default div');

document.querySelector('.select-random').addEventListener('change', () => {

  let selectedIndex = event.target.selectedIndex;  

  //if selectedIndex = 0, default is selected so all divs will be displayed, otherwise all divs will be removed
  divs.forEach(div => div.style.display = (selectedIndex === 0)? 'block':'none');
  if(selectedIndex === 0)  return;

  //the coresponding div to the selected option will be displayed
  divs[selectedIndex -1].style.display = 'block';  //-1 to componsate for the first(default) option

})
```

```html
<select class='select-random'>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="a">first</option>
  <option value="b">second</option>
  <option value="c">third</option>
  <option value="d">fourth</option>
</select>

<div id="default">
  <div id="a">Random1</div>
  <div id="b">Random2</div>
  <div id="c">Random3</div>
  <div id="d">Random4</div>
</div>
```